# Simple MySQL if query syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, if-statement

edit: my table schema below is poorly normalized as suggested and I have revamped it.

[image: schema]

Comment: What happens when you run the query?

Comment: wait, why is there varieble after select? what is the column you are trying to get? Do you have special column for every user?

Comment: It tells me that "It's NULL!". I tried to echo back ($result) but it gives me nothing at all?

Comment: I am using PHP to write these SQL statements. The variables are values extracted from an android form and that side works, as do the variables. My SQL, though, isn't very good and I think that is where the error is coming from.

Comment: can you please add your table structure, i believe problem is wrong query

Comment: I will do now, I need to load it on photobucket though as I dont have enough reputation yet!

Comment: http://i21.photobucket.com/albums/b259/acidburn942/useranswertable.png

Comment: And yes, I do have a special column for ever user..

Comment: try it with `mysql_num_rows()` also check if `$userid` is ok - place it in echo or something, query should be ok, so there must be problem in variable or condition

Comment: mysql_num_rows will always return 1, $userid echos fine...

Comment: edited my answer, try that please, if it wont solve it then i have no idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `mysql_num_rows()` in your condition

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo (" It's NULL!");
    // if null, run a query!
} else {
echo (" It's not null...");
// if not null, echo back meessage saying not null.
}
```

EDIT: nevermind

EDIT2: Gosh, I see it now, try

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row[$userid] == NULL) {
    echo (" It's NULL!");
    // if null, run a query!
} else {
echo (" It's not null...");
// if not null, echo back meessage saying not null.
}
```

Comment: weirdly, i've made each individual user have individual columns so that i can store their question responses in each one. Check this image of my table to see if you get what I mean... http://s21.photobucket.com/albums/b259/acidburn942/?action=view&current=useranswertable.png

Comment: Your last example will probably work, but this is a really bad idea to store users in columns. OP: You might want to reconsider your data schema because this is badly normalized and not scalable at all.

Comment: I know, just trying to solve the current problem, not even pointing out possible sql injection vulnerability. Redesigning that db would be best solution

Comment: Pierre-OlivierBourgeois and Uriel_SVK thank you very much for both your input. Uriel's solution does now solve the problem but I am always learning! I will look more into my database structure and try to make it better. Thank you for the tips Pierre!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mysql_num_rows()` for checking how many rows are returned,

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo (" It's NULL!");
    // if null, run a query!
}
else
{
    echo (" It's not null...");
    // if not null, echo back meessage saying not null.
}
```

Also, what column are you trying to select ?

Comment: here is my table structure: http://s21.photobucket.com/albums/b259/acidburn942/?action=view&current=useranswertable.png  
the column i am trying to select is userid, to check if it is null according to a certain question id....

Comment: You used a column per user ? This is poorly normalized. Take a look at this: http://www.asciiflow.com/#5355087028660164263/2004018477

Comment: And then, you could do a `SELECT COUNT(1) from userAnswers WHERE id = $qid AND userid = $userid` which will return you the number of rows for this specific condition.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is my first attempt at a questions/answer database. I will look more into my database structure and try to improve it! :)